# Handle server side error with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngrx

I have a form and I handle my server-side error like this.

```
  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.containerTypes$ = store.pipe(select(fromWelcome.getCts));
    this.errors$ = store.pipe(select(fromModal.getError) as any);
    this.errors$.subscribe(errors => {
      if (errors) {
        if (errors.username) {
          this.usernameError = errors.username;
          this.regForm.controls['username'].setErrors({usernameServerError: this.usernameError});
          // <-------- I want to call my mat-error here
        }
      }
    }
    );

    this.regForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])
    });
```

In .html I do this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="regForm.controls['username'].hasError('usernameServerError')"> {{usernameError}} </mat-error>
```

Unfortunately whey I get error after trying submit it does not appears under my input. I need to click input first, or submit form once again. How could I show my error right after I receive it in my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to enable my form

```
  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.containerTypes$ = store.pipe(select(fromWelcome.getCts));
    this.errors$ = store.pipe(select(fromModal.getError) as any);
    this.errors$.subscribe(errors => {
      if (errors) {
        this.regForm.enable() // <---- here
        if (errors.username) {
          this.usernameError = errors.username;
          this.regForm.controls['username'].setErrors({usernameServerError: this.usernameError});
        }
      }
    }
    );

    this.regForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)])
    });
```